# How to call async function in CakePHP with waiting for response

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
$url = $serverHttpHost."/apis/xyz";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($orderData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

How should i call the function in async mode as we are having an script that's take too much time that we need to run in background mode.

Comment: move it out to a shell and run via exec

Comment: I already done via shell but i want to know in php?

Comment: Use a CakePHP shell. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html